# Ruby on Rails to Postgres Binary encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, encoding

I have a Ruby on Rails + Postgresql app that saves file images into db, in some postgres installations data is saved erroneously in what it looks like a different bytea format, so the image in some postgres installation fails to return file correctly

**WORKING SAVED DATA**

> \xFF\xD8\xFF\xE1\x00\x\xFF\xEE\x00\x0EAdobe\x00d\xC0\x00\x00\x00\x01\xFF\xDB\x00\x84\x00\x06\x04\x04\x04\x05\x04\x06\x05\x05\x06\t\x06\x05\x06\t\v\b\x06\x06\b\v\f\n\n\v\n\n\f\x10\f\f\f\f\f\f\x10\f\x0E\x0F\x10\x0F\x0E\f\x13\x13\x14\x14\x13\x13\x1C\e\e\e\x1C\x1F\x1F\x1F\x1F\x1F\x1F\x1F\x1F\x1F\x1F\x01\a\a\a\r\f\r\x18\x10\x10\x18\x1A\x15\x11\x15

**NON WORKING SAVED DATA**

> x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000014a0000003d0806000000cb7920c80000001974455874536f6674776172650041646f626520496d616765526561647971c9653c000047eb4944415478daec5d07781455d79e99edbdef269bb62940208426bd4a5110503e51c40e28d8051145fcec62ff4041c08628624169a28234419ad2a477d2934db2bdf736ffb95bc226a46c4240f1cf7d9e81ecececade7bef73de79e7b062749126b4b6da92db5a5b6d470

any suggestions??

[image: Screenshot]

### RoR

**On RoR i do this to save the file**

```
data = (!file.nil?) ? file.read.force_encoding("UTF-8") : nil

Brand.create!({name: brand[:name], value: brand[:value], file: file,  file_properties: get_file_properties(file_url), default: brand[:default], data: data})
```

and to get the the file image

```
image_tag(o.get_base64_image, style: 'max-width:100%')
```

**With the model method**

```
def get_base64_image
    return self.data != nil ? 'data:image/png;base64,' +     Base64.encode64(self.data) : ""
  end
```

Server encoding for both servers is UTF-8

### Postgres

**potgresql.conf**

```
bytea_output = 'escape'
```

**Working Server**

```
List of databases
        Name        |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |     Access privileges     
--------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------
 postgres            | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

**Non-working server**

```
List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collation  |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | es_MX.UTF-8 | es_MX.UTF-8 |
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. I suggest that you tell us what you're trying to do... let us know why you're expecting a particular encoding over the other... show us the code you have so far and what you've tried to solve it... then we can begin to try to help you :)

Comment: Also: why does the different encoding matter? Does it actually work anyway? Is there actually an error? Can you show us what the actual error is instead of just telling us that the db stores things in different encodings?

Comment: I ve added more information above thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the output of BYTEA column in postgresql, i solved like this:

```
ALTER ROLE postgres SET bytea_output TO 'escape';
```